# How can I solve validation logic in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

In this code , if it is always displaying password does not match when I'm still giving the correct password. I'm unable to figure out exactly what's happening here! Pls help me with this.

```
def Guide_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST.get('first_name')
        lastname = request.POST.get('last_name')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        image = request.POST.get('image')
        city = request.POST.get('city')

        if password1 == password2:
            if Guide_Register.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request,'Username already exists!')
                return redirect('guideregister')
            else:
                if Guide_Register.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(request,'Email already exists!')
                    return redirect('guideregister')
                else:
                    guide = Guide_Register.objects.create(first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname,username=username,email=email,password=password1,confirm_password=password2,guide_photo=image,city=city)
                    messages.success(request,'You are registered successfully as Guide!')
                    return redirect('guidelogin')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Password does not match!')
            return redirect('guideregister')

    else:
     return render(request,'accounts/guide_register.html')
```

Comment: passwords in django are not stored as plain text and i think this is the problem.

Comment: @ehsanbakefayat You are correct, but obviously the passwords weren't stored before the validation was done. In fact, no information was being stored here either.

Comment: @Rishi Gupta if the suggested answer from @Damien Baldy didn't work, then you might have to re-edit your question and add the `html` `form` to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly advised to use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms) when doing form validation, you might want to take a look at it. You would need to write a custom `def clean(self, cleaned_data)` function in the form class to check that `password1` and `password2` match, [reading this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms) might be useful.

As for your problem, I suspect that your posted data is lacking either `password1` or `password2`, you might want to check on the template side that you have input fields for both `password1` and `password2`:

```
<input name="password1" type="password" />
<input name="password2" type="password" />
```

To check what is exactly being posted, you might want to debug using `print(request.POST)` before `if password1 == password2:` and check what the backend receives.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! It solved my problem. Really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Hi Rishi, if that solved the issue, could you please mark the answer as solution? Thank you.